# Attaching a 3 mm fiber optic cable to a WS2812 LED

Tags: led, glue, ws2812b

I am wondering how to easily attach a side-glowing fiber optic cable (I have 3 mm here) to a cheap WS2812 LED that is flat and soldered onto a PCB ([like these here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10-1000pcs-4-Pin-WS2812B-WS2812-LED-Chip-Heatsink-5V-5050-RGB-WS2811-IC-Built-in/32634454437.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.16.f6102d97cIkdew&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10320_10065_10068_10547_319_317_10548_10696_10924_10084_453_454_10083_10618_10920_10921_10304_10922_10307_10820_10821_537_10302_536_10843_10059_10884_10887_100031_10319_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=7c64ffbf-9d44-4846-8616-495d15e3d138-2&algo_pvid=7c64ffbf-9d44-4846-8616-495d15e3d138)).

I tried with Sugru, hot glue, super glue but nothing *really* stuck. In addition, I'm losing too much light at the bottom and not enough is actually going into the fiber.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Are there some sort of cool contraptions including lenses that I'm unaware off? Anything else?

Comment: please attach images

Comment: Fiber optics has an acceptance angle of sorts. With quartz, this is about plus and minus 30 degrees (60 degrees total) for the cone angle. Something like about 0.85 steradians. Sapphire achieves about \$\pi\$ steradians (a lot more.) But your fiber probably doesn't couple sapphire to the quartz. You'll need to compare the LED angles vs the fiber acceptance angles. You may also need to worry about loss due to internal reflection of steeper angles. There's a lot to consider in getting the most out of this.

Comment: @SatishSingupuram i linked the LED. what kind of image do you want? the picture of a Fiber? I haven't managed to attach anything in the right way yet, so i'm looking for ideas how to do it :)

Comment: @jonk can you give me an example? like assuming i have the right crystal / prism (where can i get these in the right size cheaply) how would i couple the stuff correctly?

Comment: You need a light pipe.

Comment: those modules do not contain a single LED ..... there are three or four LEDs ..... what is the intended purpose for the completed device?

Comment: pour a thick layer of transparent epoxy over the LED .... use a short tube to keep the epoxy contained in a cylindrical shape ..... then drill a 3mm hole through the epoxy toward the LED .... put a drop of fresh epoxy into the bottom of the hole and insert the fibre ..... you may have to somehow polish the bottom of the drilled hole before inserting the fibre  ............... first test this idea by using epoxy to glue the fiber to the LED

Comment: @jsotola true. there's 3-4 LEDs. i want to sew the fiber to clothing.

Comment: @Passerby what is a light pipe?

Comment: not the same as your project though ... https://makezine.com/projects/how-to-connect-optical-fibers-to-leds-and-sensors/

Comment: @jsotola totally coincidence that I used the same link in my update. I swear lol.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from a light pipe, a hard plastic version of fiber optic cable that is used in most commercial products to redirect light from a surface mount led

[image]

you can use a clear epoxy to mate the fiber optic cable to the 5050 package. You must make sure you use enough to create a structurally strong connection. This is why your other attempts fail, as hot glue and super glue will crack as you put lateral force on the 90 degree connection. This won't be easy as you have to hold the cable in place as the epoxy cures. This would probably require a jig of some sort.

**An alternative, is to use a 5mm version of the WS2812 led**

[image]

and either heat shrink the fiber optic cable onto it

[image]

or drill a hole and slide the cable in (instructions (and pictures) from [makezine](https://makezine.com/projects/how-to-connect-optical-fibers-to-leds-and-sensors/)).

[image]

Comment: You can also find flat top WS2812B, here for example  https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12999  https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/9/9/5/0/12999-01.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Light pipes with side emission are used a lot in automotive. My 2015 Camaro SS2 convertible comes with light pipes in the door.

Search around the automotive add on markets.

[image]
Source: [camaro5.com](https://www.camaro5.com/forums/showthread.php?t=48507)

---

This might do the trick.  It will be a very close fit. 
This one is for 2 mm flexible light piping and RGB LEDs.

The WS2812 is 5mm x 5mm

[image]

---

This light pipe adapter with a PCB mount has just enough clearance for the WS2812.

[image]

**DATASHEET**: [Bivar R2F-XX-XXX](https://www.bivar.com/portals/0/products/R2F-X.X-XXX.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Some time since this was posted but I have been looking at the same basic issue but with the RGB LEDs rather than the RGBW LEDs.  I have come to the conclusion that there is a basic problem relevant to either - possibly more so with RGBW.

The attached image shows the arrangement and dimensions of of a typical SMD RGB 5050 WS2812 LED.  As jonk stated above, the 'fibre' has an acceptance angle. If you only have a single tiny (but finite sized) light source then locating it at the right distance and axially aligned will get a certain (possibly useful) amount of the light into the fibre.
With normal fibre optic the central 'light conductor' (I am not even trying to use specific correct terminology here as I am not expert at the subject) is somewhat smaller in diameter than the overall fibre diameter.
I am not sure if sideglow is arranged exactly the same. However let us assume that for 3mm sideglow the 'entry aperture for the light is probably <3mm.
With a row of 3 light sources (R, G & B) spanning about 1.4 mm it is not possible to get optimal alignment simultaneously for each source.  If you align it on the middle source (Red) then the green and the blue will be significantly dimmer.  In my experiments I can get 2 colours simultaneously but not all 3.  With an RGBW LED the problem is greater as you now have 4 spatially separated sources.
As far as I have been able to establish simple optics cannot easily correct this. I suspect (not tested) that, with reasonable limits, increasing the fibre diameter may help. I have not tested this yet though.
[image: Typical addressable RGB LED - diagram with dimensions]

Comment: I think your question is either theoretical or related to industrial production. I ended up 3d-printing connectors and it works "just fine". Could I get more out of it? Surely. But I don't mass produce, I just prototype :)